# ElasticSearch Connection settings

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I just created ElasticSearch class and find some codes for elasticsearch connection settings but i know i am using NEST 7.0 and these codes i found are lower version than 7.0 so, how i can change to current version because i am getting some errors. Thanks in advance.

```
private static readonly ConnectionSettings connSettings = new ConnectionSettings(new Uri("http://localhost:9200/"))
                       .DefaultIndex("change_history")
                      .DefaultMappingFor(m => m
                       .Add(typeof(ChangeLog), "change_history"));
        private static readonly ElasticClient elasticClient = new ElasticClient(connSettings);
```

especially the defaultmapping part :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [configuration options documentation has an example](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/configuration-options.html#_connectionsettings_with_elasticclient). Adapted for your example

```cs
private static readonly ConnectionSettings connSettings = 
    new ConnectionSettings(new Uri("http://localhost:9200/"))
        .DefaultIndex("change_history")
        .DefaultMappingFor<ChangeLog>(m => m
            .IndexName("change_history")
        );

private static readonly ElasticClient elasticClient = new ElasticClient(connSettings);
```